# How to let JsonTextReader ignore current record and continue to next one?

Tags: json, powershell

I'm trying to use powershell to invoke the namespace Newtonsoft.Json to deal with large size of Json files. Each file contains millions of json records and not all of them are in correct format. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader since it reads one json record each time other than read the whole file into memory. But when it read to a record which contains some format problem, it will fail and i have no idea how to ignore current one.
Is there any way to let it ignore current record and continue the next one?

```
$file="C:\logtest\log-3.json"
add-type -path "C:\logtest\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"

$sr=new-object system.IO.StreamReader($file)
$reader=new-object Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader($sr)
$analyzer=New-Object Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer
$analyzer.ReferenceLoopHandling=[Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling]::Ignore

$i=0
$n=0

while($reader.read()){
    if($n -gt 2){

        if($reader.TokenType.ToString() -eq "StartObject"){
             $single=$null
            $single=$analyzer.Deserialize($reader)

            # Deal with the json record...
            $i++
        }
    }
    $n++
}
$reader.Close()
```

And here is the exception when it facing format issue:

```
Exception calling "Deserialize" with "1" argument(s): "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: ". Path 'records[46796].properties.userAgent', line 374378, position 634."
At line:6 char:13
+             $single=$analyzer.Deserialize($reader)
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JsonReaderException

Exception calling "Read" with "0" argument(s): "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: ". Path 'records[46796].properties.userAgent', line 374378, position 634."
At line:1 char:7
+ while($reader.read()){
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JsonReaderException
```

Here is an example json file, as you can see there is format issue for the property "P2" of the 3rd record.

```
{
    "Record":
        [
            {
                "P1":"data",
                "P2":"data",
                "P3":"data"
            }
            ,
            {
                "P1":"data2",
                "P2":"data2",
                "P3":"data2"
            }
            ,
            {
                "P1":"data3",
                "P2":"data3"",
                "P3":"data3"
            }
            ,
            {
                "P1":"data4",
                "P2":"data4",
                "P3":"data4"
            }
        ]

}
```

Comment: provide a minimum set of data to help us debug.  sounds like you have each line of a text file is a single JSON record.  Show us a 3-line sample file

Comment: @NoRefundsNoReturns Thanks for your suggestion. I add an example at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

What about a Try Catch statement?

```
     try {
 $single=$analyzer.Deserialize($reader)

        # Deal with the json record...
        $i++ }

 catch {
LogWrite ("Caught the exception")
LogWrite ($Error[0].Exception)
$i++
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, since the $reader keeps on current record which contains problem. It is not able to read the next record. You can have a try with the example json file at the end of question description.